# Generate variant strings based on replacement dictionary for some words only in Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

Given a string and a word replacement dictionary, I'm trying to get python to return all variant strings. E.g. for the string "One went to market", and the replacement dict {'One': ['One','Two','Three'], 'market': ['town','bed']} I want to return: ['One went to town','Two went to town','Three went to town', One went to bed','Two went to bed','Three went to bed']. Currently I have this working only when there are two replacement options.

My partially working approach uses word lists generated from the dictionary, e.g. in the example above, I have ['One,Two,Three','went','to','town,bed']. This this:

```
def perm(wordlist):
    a=[[]]
    for i in wordlist:
        if ',' in i:
            wds=i.split(',')
            for alis in a:
                alis.append(wds[0])
            for j in wds[1:]:
                b=[x[:-1] for x in a]
                for alis in b:
                    alis.append(j)
                    a=a+b
        else:
            for alis in a:
                alis.append(i)
    return a
```

for ['One,Two','went','to','town,bed'] I get the required result, but any time there's more than two options it's haywire.

Comment: What have you tried till now? Can you post your code?

Comment: Also, how do you want to handle duplicates? How would "One went to Hotel One more time" be handled? Do you want 3 sentences or 9 to be generated in this case?

Comment: 9 sentences in this case (though with my inputs probably this won't arise.)

Comment: Code is pasted in now - sorry it took some time to format things right - I'm new

Answer (score 0):

Supposedly you have these:

```
string = "One went to market"
dict_repl = {'One':['One','Two','Three'],'market':['town','bed']}
```

you can get your expected result using this one liner using [string comprehension](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) and [str.replace](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm):

```
result = [string.replace('market',v).replace('One',i) for v in dict_repl['market'] for i in dict_repl['One']]
```

output:

```
['One went to town', 'Two went to town', 'Three went to town', 'One went to bed', 'Two went to bed', 'Three went to bed']
```

I believe this is what you're asking for.

Comment: Thanks, that's the desired output, but how would you adapt it to thousands of different inputs, with a dictionary of a few dozen keys and a few hundred values?

Comment: and you still want One, Two and Three to iterate over your different other words like "One went to market with Annie", "One went to market with Mikasa" then with " Two " then with "Three" ? I don't really get the combinations you're looking for @Smallpip

Comment: yes exactly: one with mikasa, two with mikasa, three with mikasa, one with annie, two with annie, etc.. So all words with entries in repl_dict generate a new string with all other words in repl_dict, and words with no entries remain common to all strings.